# Telerik Kendo Grid DateTime column is always null

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Telerik Kendo Grid with several bound columns. All columns are working as expected except this DateTime-column **tsCreated**, which is **always null**.

The Model:

```
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime tsCreated { get; set; }
```

The Grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<NNC.ViewModels.OrderViewModel>()
        .Name("grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.tsCreated);
            columns.Bound(c => c.orderNr);
            columns.Bound(c => c.customerName);
            columns.Bound(c => c.description);                
        })
        .Groupable()
        .Filterable()
        .Sortable()
        .Pageable()
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Events(events => events.Error("kendoGrid_ErrorHandler"))
            .Model(model => model.Id("orderNr"))
            .Read(read => read.Action("EditingInline_Read", "Orders"))                
        )
)
```

The JSON data does show the date in **tsCreated**:

```
{
 "Data":[{"orderNr":"13011155","tsCreated":"\/Date(1423579599377)\/",
 "description":"xxxx","customerName":"xxxxx"}],"Total":1,
 "AggregateResults":null,"Errors":null
 }
```

I also created a ClientTemplate to display the value, like this:

```
columns.Bound(c => c.tsCreated).ClientTemplate(
                "W= #= tsCreated #"
            );
```

But it displays:

```
W= null
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you using Globalize.js? Because Kendo UI conflicts with Globalize.js. To fix this just load Kendo before Globalize.

Comment: Thank you @NicolásCarlo, I added this as the answer. If you would like to do that yourself, please to and I will accept that as the answer. Many thanks, costs me way to many hours, but that's the way you learn ;-)

Comment: Added that as the answer. I'm glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem happens if you're using `Globalize.js`. Kendo UI conflicts with Globalize's date functions so currently the workaround is to load `Globalize.js` after Kendo UI related scripts.

Here's the relevant discussion on Telerik's forum (found at: http://www.telerik.com/forums/registering-globalize-js-before-kendo-culture-js-causes-datetime-columns-in-grids-to-fail-formatting):

> Basically when you load the globalize library, kendo.parseDate starts
>   using Globalize.parseDate method instead of our own implementation of
>   kendo.parseNumber. And since the globalize parser is not able to parse
>   the format that the MVC returns the date successfully.
>
> e.g.
>
> Globalize.parseDate("/Date(-47876400000)/")
>
> Loading the globalize library after the Kendo scripts wont override
>   our implementation and the Grid will parse it successfully.
>
> I am afraid there is no other work-around to this case.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the date conversion from UNIX epoch is failing? Can try using the Kendo UI date conversion.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<NNC.ViewModels.OrderViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.tsCreated).ClientTemplate("W= #= kendo.toString(tsCreated , "m") #");
        columns.Bound(c => c.orderNr);
        columns.Bound(c => c.customerName);
        columns.Bound(c => c.description);                
    })
    .Groupable()
    .Filterable()
    .Sortable()
    .Pageable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Events(events => events.Error("kendoGrid_ErrorHandler"))
        .Model(model => model.Id("orderNr"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("EditingInline_Read", "Orders"))                
        )
)
```

Comment: Thank you @Vash. Well I did output the value of tsCreated in a ClientTemplate (see Question) and it clearly shows it's null. However, the solution is already given by Nicolás Carlo's.

Comment: Yeah, just noticed your answer after posting mine. In your question you didn't have the `kendo.ToString()`. Anyway your issue is different, perhaps it helps someone else with a similar issue. :)